# Cannot return map<text,text> from User Defined Function in CQL 3.x (Cassandra 2.2.3)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, cql3, datastax-java-driver

I am not able to return map from User Defined Function in CQL 3.x (Cassandra 2.2.3). Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION issaviktempkeyspace.myfilter1(begindate timestamp,argtimestamp timestamp,columnname text,columnvalue text,companyid int) 
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
RETURNS map<text,text> LANGUAGE java AS
'
if(begindate.before(argtimestamp)){
    Map<String,String> map= Collections.<String,String>emptyMap();
    map.put("columnname",columnname);
    map.put("columnvalue",columnvalue);
    map.put("companyid",Integer.toString(companyid));
    return map;
}
else
    return null;
';
```

When I try to create the function, Cassandra says that,

```
InvalidQueryException: Could not compile function 'issaviktempkeyspace.myfilter1' from Java source: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: Java source compilation failed:
Line 3: Map cannot be resolved to a type
Line 3: Collections cannot be resolved
  com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: InvalidQueryException: Could not compile function 'issaviktempkeyspace.myfilter1' from Java source: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: Java source compilation failed:
Line 3: Map cannot be resolved to a type
Line 3: Collections cannot be resolved
```

-- Any idea how to do this.
I have one more query. Can I have tuple type to be returned as a part of UDF ?